# When does adding edges decrease the cover time of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, pr.probability

When first learning about random walks on a graph $G$, one may have an intuitive feeling that adding edges to $G$ will decrease its cover time $C(G)$.  However, this is not the case.  The [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) $P_n$ has cover time $C(P_n) = \Theta(n^2)$ while the [($\frac{n}{2}$, $\frac{n}{2}$)-lollipop graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LollipopGraph.html) $L_{\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}}$ has cover time $C(L_{\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}}) = \Theta(n^3)$.  Eventually adding edges does decrease the cover time because the complete graph $K_n$ has cover time $C(K_n) = \Theta(n \log n)$ by analogy to the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Under what assumptions though would the supposed intuition hold true?  Specifically, what about [vertex transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph)?

> Let $G$ be a vertex-transitive graph with $n$ vertices.  Consider any vertex-transitive graph $G^+$ obtained from $G$ by adding edges (i.e. both $G$ and $G^+$ are vertex transitive and $G$ is a spanning subgraph of $G^+$).
>
> Is it the case that $C(G^+) \le C(G)$?

Comment: Wouldn't the complete graph $K_{n}$ and any of its subgraphs $K_{k}$, $k < n$ be a counterexample for general vertex transitivity?

Comment: @chazisop Those subgraphs are not spanning.

Comment: My bad, I confused spanning with induced.